# How to I detect if each number in the list is equal to or below zero?

Tags: python

[image]

I have -1 as each element in the list but it still prints "there is a positive"

Thanks in advance,

WG

Comment: Why don't you print `all(test_3)`?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do

```
if max(test_3) <= 0:
    print("all negative")
else:
    print("there is a positive")
```

This seems more explicit to me that you want the maximum value to be 0 or less

Answer (score 3):

`all()` checks if all items in an array are True, then returns a boolean. To check if a number is less than zero in the list, you can do:
`all([i>=0 for i in [-1,-2,-3,3]])`